# How to create measure in Power BI following condition on Fact and Dim

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have 1 Fact and 2 Dim and how can I create measure on condition

1. DIM_DATE.U_DATE > Todaydate  ==> 0
2. DIM_TRAN.EXPIRY_DATE <= Todaydate ==> FACT_TRAN.Value
   3.(else) DIM_DATE.U_DATE <= Todaydate && DIM_TRAN.Expiry_date > Todaydate
   == >  Datediff(DIM_DATE.U_DATE,DIM_TRAN.EXPIRY_DATE) * FACT_TRAN.Value/Datediff(DIM_DATE.U_DATE,DIM_TRAN.EXPIRY_DATE)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSRCf.png)

file to download .pbix  ==> https://easyupload.io/rr3b0w

I try to use switch
Like this : Test M = SWITCH(TRUE(),
SELECTEDVALUE(DIM_DATE[U_DATE]) > TODAY(),0,1)
but value is multiple.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8F1n.png)

Comment: https://easyupload.io/rr3b0w  file to download .PBIX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i have used [IF](https://dax.guide/if/) dax function and [selectedvalue](https://dax.guide/selectedvalue/) dax function to buld the dax query. Logic is a bit unclear to me, but I have created the logic as you intended.

```
_calmeasure = 
VAR todaydate =
    TODAY ()
VAR udate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( DIM_DATE[U_DATE] )
VAR expiry =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( DIM_TRAN[EXPIRY_DATE] )
VAR cond =
    IF (
        udate > todaydate,
        0,
        IF (
            expiry <= todaydate,
            CALCULATE ( MAX ( FACT_TRAN[Value] ) ),
            IF (
                udate <= todaydate
                    && expiry > todaydate,
                DATEDIFF ( udate, expiry, DAY ) * SELECTEDVALUE ( FACT_TRAN[Value] )
                    / DATEDIFF ( udate, expiry, DAY ),
                0
            )
        )
    )
RETURN
    cond
```

Comment: Thank you very much it help me to solve it